# How to Animate Visibility.Collapsed + Update StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I think my title is a bit confusing so let me explain my question in detail.

I have a StackPanel with multiple Grids inside it. It basicly looks like a table with a "Header Grid" and a "Content Grid" below. The StackPanel itself is inside a ScrollViewer. 
Whenever the user clicks on the "Header Grid" the corresponding "Content Grid" should be collapsed and visible vice versa.

Here is a short version of my table:

```
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid x:Name="Header_Grid1" Height="24" Background="#BF101820" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="34,0,0,0" Cursor="Hand" >
                <Label Content="Click me to show/hide Content_Grid1"  Padding="5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="982"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="Content_Grid1" Height="100" Width="967" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label Content="some content"  Foreground="#FF918F82" Padding="5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,719,75"/>
                <Label Content="some content"  Foreground="#FF918F82" Padding="5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,719,50"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="Header_Grid2" Height="24" Background="#BF101820" Width="1001" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Label Content="Click me to show/hide Content_Grid2"  Padding="5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="982"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="Content_Grid2" Height="100" Width="967" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Label Content="some content"  Foreground="#FF918F82" Padding="5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,719,75"/>
                <Label Content="some content"  Foreground="#FF918F82" Padding="5,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,25,719,50"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer >
```

Lets say the user clicks on "Header_Grid1" the "Content_Grid1" hides with an kinda "flow to the top" animation by reducing its size. Thats no problem at all - the thing is I´d like the "Header_Grid2" aswell as the "Content_Grid2" to flow to the top while the animation of hiding "Content_Grid1" is playing. "Header_Grid2" and "Content_Grid2" should not just pop to the place where "Content_Grid1" has been. It should rather happen in a smooth animation.

Hopefully someone understands what I mean. It´s pretty hard to explain...
Thanks

Comment: Please consider using WPF correctly, the xaml is unreadable. Don't use Drag&Drop but work with panels, alignments and margin.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I'm new to xaml and just used WinForms before. My code is pretty much toolbox drag and drop like you mentioned but nobody is perfect and since I'm coding on a hobby basis it will take some time for me to fully understand xaml.

Comment: I would really like to help you, but you make it quite hard. Anyways, as a tip for the future, just close the toolbox and never open it again, you don't need it when programming with WPF, just declare the controls with the help of intellisense, then you don't have ugly constructs like your code.
Anyways, can you please explain why the Header2 is not floating up? When you reduce the height of the ContentGrid1, then the header should close up the gap (because it's in the same StackPanel).

Comment: Yes thanks for the advice I'll try my best to avoid the toolbox from now on. I really don't know why Header2 doesn't floats up. It simply sits at it's place untill the animation that resizes ContentGrid1 is finished. Then Header2 just pops to where Content1 has been.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code which resizes the ContentGrid1? I think that there's something going wrong.

Comment: Well that gave me an idea. I´ve never changed the actual height of ContentGrid1. By just adjusting the size in the designer view all I´ve changed were some RenderTransform values. I´m using VS Blend by the way. Anyways thanks for bringing me on the right track.

Comment: Ah, yes, changing RenderTransform won't rearrange the controls (you better use LayoutTransform). But animating the Height with a DoubleAnimation might be the best way to do that. So you solved your problem? I wish you a nice day and a lot of fun with WPF in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you can't animate the collapsed method, but there are various tricks to get around that such as animating the opacity, size, location etc...